# Debug app emulando no celular

Tags: android, android-studio

Estou com um problema em que uma conversão `string para double`, em que no `emulador o APP está funcionando` perfeitamente, mas `no celular ele trava` e fecha.

Gostaria de saber como fazer para `debugar se quando executo o app no celular`, ele `não tem o debug no logcat`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existe sim a possibilidade de visualizar o log do dispositivo pelo LogCat basta selecionar o nome do dispositivo na aba do LogCat. Veja a imagem.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tente ver também nas opções de desenvolvedor do seu celular se a opção depuração usb está habilidata.

Comment: Eu nem vou comentar, só vou ir comprar um óculos ! kkkk Obrigado colega !